# Intuition into Expectation Value of Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Continuous random variable analogue of the expectation value is
$$
E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx
$$
where $f(x)$ is the probability density function

My confusion is in getting a picture of the above expression for the expectation value of the continuous variable from that of the discrete variable. How do we get to the integral expression for the expectation value for the continuous variable from the summation in the discrete case ?

**What I do know**

The expectation value is nothing but the weighted sum of variables. Thus for a discrete random variable $X$,
$$
E[X]=\sum_i x_iP(X=x_i)
$$
where $P(X=x_i)$ is the probability mass function which gives the probability when the variable takes the value $x_i$.

For continuous variable we can only find the probability for short intervals, say $[a,b]$
$$
P(X)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$$

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ : area under the curve $f(x)$

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ : sum of $f(x)dx$ from $a$ to $b$

Comment: Consider a step function for $f$, so that $X$ is uniformly distributed in certain intervals (with certain weights).

Comment: @Berci step intervals are equally spaced, ie., $dx$, thus in each interval we have the probability $f(x)dx$, right ?

Comment: @Berci but how do I extend that for the expectation value ?

Comment: Yes, easiest to think about a function of the form $f(x)=\phi(\lfloor x\rfloor)$, then $X$ can also be viewed as a discrete variable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32953/321264 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666564/321264 might help.